# How to deserialize a spring data jpa entity from HATEOAS uri in GET request in custom RestController

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hateoas

I have a problem in my custom Spring RestController that needs a refernce to a spring-data-jpa entity as its input in a GET request. Here is my code:

I have a spring data jpa entity called "AreaModel". It just simply has some String attributes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "areas")
public class AreaModel {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long id;

  public String title;
  public String description;
  [...]
}
```

This JPA entity is also exposed via spring-data-rest as a spring-hateoas rest repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "areas", path = "areas", itemResourceRel = "area")
public interface AreaRepo extends CrudRepository<AreaModel, Long> {
  [...]
}
```

CRUD operations via GET and POST to this rest endpoint work fine.

But now I have a custom controller that needs an AreaModel as its input. The Client requests a "token" for one given area.  All the client knows is the "HATEOAS ID" of the area. HATEOAS IDs actually are URIs, e.g. /myBasePath/areas/4711

Here is my (not yet working) custom rest controller:

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class VoteRestController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/getToken")
  public @ResponseBody Map getToken(@RequestParam("area")AreaModel area, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserModel user) throws LiquidoException {
    log.info(user+" requests a voter token for area "+area);


  }
```

The client request that I am trying to get to work is

```
GET /myBasePath/getToken?area=/myBasePath/areas/4711
```

The error I get in the Spring exception is:

```
"exception": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
"message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.doogie.liquido.model.AreaModel'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value '/liquido/v2/areas/42'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"/liquido/v2/areas/42\"",
"path": "/liquido/v2/getToken"
```

Expected result

**How can I pass a (refernce to a) spring-data-hateos resource to a custom rest controller as a request parameter of a GET request?**

Comment: How about passing the ID, and using it on the server to get the area from the database? That's what IDs are for. If you really want to pass the path of the area (why?), then parse it to extract the ID out of it, and get the area from the database using the ID.

Comment: Yes you are right, that one _COULD_  use the ID. But the web client should not know about internal database IDs. It should not know the syntax of the URIs.  For the client those URIs are just "reference IDs". This seems to be an open (and very much discussed) issue in spring-data-rest.  It exposes URIs as IDs. But it does not offer any way to convert these URIs back to entities in the backend.